# Do not close the application after an unsuccessful attempt to connect to the database java.net.ConnectException database: Connection refused

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

Spring Boot Data/Postgres.

**Problem:**
If the resource-database (postgres) is not available when the application starts, the application will fail with an error.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

**Question**:
How can I get the application to automatically try to reconnect?

**Assumptions:**
Use `Spring-Retry` project to wrap @*entityManagerFactory* bean with retry  attempts.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried handling the exception?

Try to handle this exception and upon the occurance, the appliaction can re-try connecting to the DB. Of course it would be beneficial to give the user the oportunity to decide if he wishes to re-try in order to avoid the infinite loop.

@KDecker, thank you for a valid point!

Comment: How could i catch the exception if I used Spring boot, which automatic creates BD's beans such as jdbc, datasource, jpa beans based on properties such as "spring.datasource.*" ? Did you mean to use some global application handler on the ConnectException ?